# select BLOB type image and insert it to another table

Tags: php, html

I have two table one is storing basic info with image type is blob and
the other table is for attendance table , Now my problem is when i select all
 the table with basic info with image and insert it to another table the image
column is only blank the rest has a value , Hope you can help fix it thanks.

here is my php code:

```
<?php 

include_once('connection.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit0'])){
$rfid = $_POST['rfid'];

$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from stud where rfid_num ='$rfid'");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

if ($count == 0) {
header("location:notexist.php");

    } else{

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                  $rfid=$row['rfid_num'];
                  $id=$row['id'];
                   $name0 = $row['name'];
                   $course0 = $row['course'];
                  $image = $row['image'];

     $InsertSql = "INSERT INTO student_att(rfid_num,id,name,course,image) VALUES ('$rfid','$id','$name0','$course0','$image')";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $InsertSql); 
}
}
}
?>
```

[image: this is the output of the query]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of executing two separate queries I will suggest you to have a single query which will select from one table and insert into another table.

Example query:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (st_id,uid,changed,status,assign_status)
SELECT st_id,from_uid,now(),'Pending','Assigned'
FROM table1
```

NOTE: It's not good to save images in database. We usually keep them in folders and save the path of it in database.

Comment: @ace Are you looking for any other solution?

Comment: yes, but the images keeping on a folder and save the path to database, i still don't know how to do that. that's why i choose to store to image to the database

Comment: @ace google it lots of tutorials there. meanwhile you can use above single query to solve your problem or try to print all the values you are selection from db for debug purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve your error is by doing like this

```
$image=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$row['image'];
```

$mysqli is connection variable.
and then in your query use $image to insert image hope it will helps.